# Change the index for DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `datagridview` in my Windows Application. The problem is the index starts at `0` and I need to it be at `1`.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            Int32 rowIndex;
            try
            {
                rowIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
                rowIndex = rowIndex + 1;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.ToString());
```

When I click through the rows, its always out by `1` in the `index`. So the `index + 1` isn't working.

Merry Xmas

Comment: @PriceCheaperton I don't see what's the problem here. You assigned `rowIndex` variable but never used it. And `dataGridView1.CurrentRow.ToString()` will give you the current row index. To see we are on the same line, if you are on the last row of a datagridview with 3 rows, it will print 2 (first row is 0). Is that the actual result in your case?

Comment: Yes, if im on the 3rd row it will say, 2. But i want it so its row 1, index 1 or row 3 index 3

Comment: Please read this article on [Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311333/en-us)

Comment: Im working with C# not VB.NET

Comment: Ur calculating `rowIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index + 1;` but finally printing `dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index`..! It should `rowIndex.ToString()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Int32 rowIndex;
        try
        {
            rowIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
            rowIndex = rowIndex + 1;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        MessageBox.Show(rowIndex.ToString());
   }
```

Since you was calculating `rowIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index + 1;` but finally printing `dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index`. It should `rowIndex.ToString()` which has required result.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you want your row index to start with 1 because you are using it elsewhere too. If that's the case just create an empty row first and set its visible property to false.

Update: Sorry. Here's the code:

```
int i = DataGridView1.Rows.Add();
DataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = false;
```

Comment: Thank you for a kind reply. How does one set an empty row and then visible?

Answer (score 1):

In NET (but not only in NET) all the array indexes start at zero. The Rows collection of the DataGridView is not an exception.  Technically, an array index is actually an offset from the start of the array. The first element is therefore at index zero as it's offset zero elements from the start of the array.

If you want to show the `natural` (first, second, third, etc..) row number then you could simply add 1 to the `rowIndex` variable when you want to display that `natural` number, but do not use the computed value as an index for the collection.

In the old days of VB6 there was the statement `Option Base 1` that could change the base index for the arrays, but this is [no more supported by the NET framework neither for VB.NET and C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311333/en-us).

I really suggest to not fight against the rules of the Framework and follow them. If you do (supposing that you could do it right) you create a maintenance nightmare for the future.

Answer (score 1):

**All arrays and collections are zero based**, you can't change that.

However, you can show formatted string though:

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("DataGridViewRow Index = {0}",
                                dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index + 1));
```